# iOS how hide nagationBar in homepage ,Other viewcontrollers show navgationBar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a navgationController and its rootViewContoller is tabViewController,and the tableviewController contains five viewControllers,now i just want to hide navgationBar in Homepage,and i hided the navgationBar successfully by `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated]` in `viewWillAppear`, and `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated]` in `viewWillDisappear`. but when i switch to any another viewController in tabViewController,and then pop to homepage ,there is a blank above the tabbar, and its height is about 64 pixes ,and i found the tableview frame has changed!For help ! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.. You need to change the table view frame in viewdidappear of homepage.
I changed the tableview topspace constraint constant in my viewdidappear and it helped me.

Comment: i tryed according to your purpose,but it still doesn't work ,and then i set the tableview's height constant in viewdidappear ,it works well ,thank you

Comment: you are welcome..
the problem is that you need to change the constraints programmatically only after the default constraints are loaded..